# Sign and size of OLS bias for Tobit models

Tags: self-study, least-squares, censoring, tobit-regression

I have a question related to the sign and size of the OLS bias in the case of a Tobit model.

Consider the following model

(1) Sample of observations $\{X_i,Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$, i.i.d., $X_i$ is a vector $k\times 1$

(2) $
Y_i^\star=X_i'\beta +U_i
$

(3) $Y_i = \begin{cases}
  Y_i^\star & \text{if } Y^\star_i\geq0, \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$

(4) $U_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2_u)$, $U_i$ independent of $X_i$

We can show that 
$$
E(Y_i| X_i, Y_i> 0)= X_i'\beta+\sigma_u\frac{\phi(\frac{X_i'\beta}{\sigma_u})}{\Phi(\frac{X_i'\beta}{\sigma_u})}
$$

Suppose I run an OLS regression of $Y_i>0$ on $X_i$ and that I have only one regressor plus intercept. What are the sign and size of the bias of the OLS slope estimator? My thought was the following:

(i) assume $k=2$, $Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1X_i+\xi_i$ where $\xi_i:=\epsilon_i+\sigma_u\frac{\phi(\frac{X_i'\beta}{\sigma_u})}{\Phi(\frac{X_i'\beta}{\sigma_u})}$, $\epsilon_i$ independent of $X_i$

(ii) Focus on $\beta_1$

(iii) We can show that $\hat{\beta}_{1,OLS}-\beta_1\rightarrow_p \sigma_u\frac{cov(X_i, \frac{\phi(\frac{\beta_0+\beta_1X_i}{\sigma_u})}{\Phi(\frac{\beta_0+\beta_1X_i}{\sigma_u})})}{Var(X_i)}$

(iv) We know that $\frac{\phi(\frac{\beta_0+\beta_1X_i}{\sigma_u})}{\Phi(\frac{\beta_0+\beta_1X_i}{\sigma_u})}$ is decreasing in $\frac{\beta_0+\beta_1X_i}{\sigma_u}$

(v) Hence, if $\beta_1\geq 0$ then $cov(X_i, \frac{\phi(\frac{\beta_0+\beta_1X_i}{\sigma_u})}{\Phi(\frac{\beta_0+\beta_1X_i} {\sigma_u})})\leq 0$; if $\beta_1\leq 0$ then $cov(X_i, \frac{\phi(\frac{\beta_0+\beta_1X_i}{\sigma_u})}{\Phi(\frac{\beta_0+\beta_1X_i} {\sigma_u})})\geq 0$

From several sources I found that instead $\hat{\beta}_{1,OLS}$ is downward biased. Could you provide some help to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you.  You might find it helpful to consider two scenarios in which, after the $X_i$ are placed in order, (a) all the values where $Y_i=0$ are in the second half of the data and (b) all those values are in the first half of the data.  It seems to me that the direction of bias on $\hat\beta_1$ differs between those two scenarios.